# Super User doesn't want "shopping recommendations" either.

Tags: discussion, migration

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15256/any-bluetooth-keyboards-with-integrated-pointing-device-trackball-trackpad?noredirect=1) recently got migrated to Super User.
Please don't do that, shopping recommendation are as much OT there as here.

Please just close them here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure thing. Sorry about that. I did toss Ivo Flipse a heads up that that had happened, but by then the migration had already occurred.

Comment: No worries @Grace, you did the right thing :)

Answer (score 2):

My bad. To be honest I wasn't really sure it would be accepted by SU, but as it was more of a "is there *any* product like that" question than a "what are a good products that do that" question I gave it the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 1):

also got asked here

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/any-bluetooth-keyboards-with-integrated-pointing-device-trackball-trackpad

(I deleted it.)

Very confused and annoying user.