# How should we approach recommendation questions containing real technical problems?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

This [new question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15997/what-are-some-livestreaming-sites-applications-for-games) poses an actual question in spite of asking for recommendations: **How Do I Livestream Games?**

How should we approach the above question? The current answers seem to suffer from the same problems as game-recs: they are subjective and localized. On the other hand, you can't really go about fully answering the basic question without providing some examples of livestreaming sites.

Here are [two](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay) [more](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5762/where-can-one-find-a-list-of-players-ranked-by-achievement-points-for-starcraft-2) examples. The former asks how to record gameplay demos, the latter asks how to find players ranked by achievement points.

Comment: Next time, I'll think twice about suggesting you ask a question that results in an essay in the middle of the work day...

Comment: Oh man. Sorry @Grace.

Comment: You don't need to say you're sorry. Besides, I've made 4 stealthy attacks on your editing habits today already, so this is probably karma for that. ♪

Answer (score 7):

Isn't this just really the same as the old video conversion question?

[I'm sure we all fondly remember this topic and the 10-hour chat discussion leading up to it.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/video-conversion-question)

By extension of that ruling, questions on **where** to broadcast your gaming are off-topic. Tools for **how** to capture your gaming for broadcast are on-topic.  If the tool for how to capture your gaming also happens to be a place to broadcast it, then that should be on-topic as well.

Additionally, I believe that asking which free services to use is just as much "shopping advice" as asking which game to buy.

Comment: I thought we ruled the video conversion as off-topic because "What you do *post* FRAPS is off-topic", not because the topic of FRAPS itself was off-topic. This seems more inclined to be like the latter, and if that's off-topic we have got a lot of closing to do.

Comment: @Grace I meant that, by extension of that ruling, questions on *where* to broadcast your gaming are off-topic.  Tools for *how* to capture your gaming for broadcast are on-topic.

Comment: I imagine that the nature of streaming being realtime makes it that where one broadcasts is part of how you capture gaming for a broadcast - usually the site dictates, if not straight up provides, the recording software. But I'm not exactly an expert on streaming, so I'm judging just by my own expectations of how one would actually do this kind of thing. It doesn't make the question in its current form any more acceptable, but I imagine that it lends a better opening for revision, in a sense.

Comment: @Grace Ping for edited answer body.

Comment: Well, I guess that kinda works it for me. As far as a general topic is concerned. We're eventually going to need to hammer out our whole "gaming resources" topicality at some point, but for this particular question I think it's still in need of serious editing away from "what should I use" and directed more towards "what do I do", so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first two aren't specific to gaming (they could equally be asking about art casts or product demos) however the last one is specifically related and couldn't be about any other topic and therefore should be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such questions are appropriate for Gaming. You can easily take the game completely out of the equation and reduce it to `How do I stream what I am doing on my computer to The Internets?`. A question such as that has no place on Gaming.

> But Shaun,

I hear you thinking,

> it's not that simple. Games typically require special graphics libraries that often complicates this beyond what you would need to do to stream a spreadsheet tutorial.

Sure, I see where you're going with this, but that doesn't really prove your point.

> Blasphemy!

May I?

> Okay, fine.

Thank you.

Firstly, there are games that don't require such fancy libraries, correct?

> Well... yeah...

Okay. Now, what if I wanted to write a program called `Spreadsheet 3000` using OpenGL because I want to incorporate all manner of awesome effects into the mundane experience of working with spreadsheets?

> You'd be a fool!

Maybe, but I'd also be in a situation where I needed a solution that could stream `Spreadsheet 3000` on The Internet using the same tools I'd need to use for `typical games`.

> Yeah, well, it's still not likely.

I'll give you that. My point remains, though, you can remove the game from the question and the question is completely valid. Furthermore, it's not valid on Gaming. The same applies for the question on recording gameplay demos.

In addition, the question skirts the bounds of product recommendations. We're in the habit of doing that if the product is something that directly resolves a question about a game (like the SC2 Ranks example), but not if it's a question about something that doesn't result in furthering knowledge about a game (such as `If I like Spreadsheet 3000, what other games should I try?`).

With these two points in mind, let's look at the question that was asked:

> I want to live-stream some games while I play them. How do I this? What applications/websites can I use?

The first question was `How do I [stream what I am doing on my computer to users on the Internet]?`. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) would be a pretty good place to get an answer about that.

The second question was `What applications/websites can I use [to stream what I am doing on my computer to users on the Internet]?`. That sounds very much like a shopping recommendation to me. We've established that neither Gaming nor [SuperUser](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/super-user-doesnt-want-shopping-recommendations-either) wants shopping recommendations, and it would seem as if its [off-topic at WebApps as well](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/should-rec-tags-be-added).

That being said, I'm not so far gone that I don't acknowledge that the gaming community has a growing number of people interested in this information. I think a CW post about it wouldn't be a bad idea, but I think that's as far as we should take it.

Comment: Streaming games and streaming your desktop face slightly different problems and most likely need different software. Generally you're of course right, but I think in this specific case you can't take out the game of the question.

Comment: Isn't this literally my answer saying streaming isn't specific to gamimg and therfore off-topic?

Comment: @RonanForman They share similar points, however I expand on whether each type of question has a place on any SE site at all. Also, since this is a discussion question on a meta site, duplicating some of your points in my opinion on the matter is, as far as I know, reasonable in the context of the discussion. :)

Comment: Hey, why the down votes?

Comment: @RonanForman As downvoting on meta doesn't affect reputation adversely, it's more often used as an indication of disagreeing with what's been posted as opposed to indicating a low-quality post.